# Tcl regular expression to detect square brackets

Tags: regex, csv, tcl

I have a .csv files where many rows have one of the field values like this:

```
scl[0]
scl[1]
scl[2]
sda[1]
sda[2]
sda[3]
```

I am storing them in a variable while reading the csv files in line by line format,like:

```
 set string [$m get cell 0 1]
```

Now when I do regexp to check whether the cell has `scl[0]` I am unable to pass the square bracket to this regular expression:
I gave this syntax:

```
if{[regexp "scl\[0\]" $string]} {
...
}
```

But the if condition doesn't get executed.

If in case of `scl(0)`, i.e `()` instead of `{}` in csv file, I gave `{[regexp "scl\[(\]0\[)\]" $string]}` which worked. The same format I tried apply to square brackets still it doesn't get evaluated.

Am I missing something?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Note that `\` has special meaning inside double quotes. So just do:

```
regexp "scl\\[0\\]" $string
```

or:

```
regexp {scl\[0\]} $string
```

Comment: This sort of thing is why putting braces around a regular expression is a _very_ good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `string equal`: then you only need to worry about one level of quoting:

```
string equal {scl[0]} $string
```

Documentation:
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)